# How to see the common runserver log from django in heroku?

Tags: django, heroku

I am running a Django app on Heroku, and I am getting an error that I am not getting on my local machine. I am getting a 500 error. Normally, I just see the log Django outputs on the CMD, but I can't see it in Heroku. How can I do this?
BTW, it is not a dependency cause I just `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

I am not looking for the logs that appear with `heroku logs —tail` since these logs only show the heroku output. I am looking for the same logs that appear locally. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: There shouldn't be a "runserver log" since you shouldn't be using `runserver` on Heroku. What do you mean by "I am not looking for the logs that appear with `heroku logs —tail` since these logs only show the heroku output. I am looking for the same logs that appear locally"?

Comment: yes, exactly @Chris but I checked the error setting debug to true

Comment: Are you looking for the output that appears in the _browser_ in debug mode?

Comment: I was looking for the output that appears in the CMD, but then I realised that it is the same as the output in the browser in debug mode, so yeah, kindda.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the directory you connected the project to the heroku,

use the command,

```
heroku logs --tail
```

sometimes you might be asked to login to your heroku account.. if so use the

```
heroku login
```

complete the login process and try again

Comment: This shows the logs for heroku, however it doesn’t shows the logs for Django. Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: you are not sure what is causing the 500 error and want to fix that right ?

Comment: yes @ANGEETH SUBRAMONIAM

Comment: change the debug to True... Redeploy the heroku app and now you see the reason of the error in the browser as usual.... heroku log also shows what the issue is but it is clustered and bit difficult to find...

Comment: also dont forget to revoke debug to false when done...

Comment: Yeah that worked, thanks!! @ANGEETH SUBRAMONIAM